# Preg Match Empty String

Tags: regex, preg-match

How to preg_match for an null (empty) string??

I need something like:

```
/([0-9]|[NULL STRING])/
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use `^` to match beginning-of-line, and `$` to match end-of-line, thus the regular expression `^$` would match an empty line/string.

Your specific example (a line/string containing a single digit or being empty) would easiest be achieved with `^[0-9]?$`.

Comment: Or `^\d?$` - somehow I like `\d` than `[0-9]`, sorry :)

Comment: @Amarghosh: I too prefer `\d`, especially as it is a lot easier/shorter to type. Though, for regular expression beginners, I like to stick with the basics when giving examples as fancy stuff like `\d` doesn't work in all regular expression flavors.

Comment: ...and `\d` doesn't *mean* the same thing as `[0-9]` in some regex flavors. For instance, in .NET, `\d` matches `٣` (Arabic numeral 3).

Comment: please if i want to make it with more than one digit,  how can i write it ?

Answer (score 5):

With PHP's regex you can just say:

```
/(\d|)/
```

It may be usefull...

Comment: Yeah, that just matches anything. I can throw at it - not desirable.

Answer (score 1):

You can also match a null character with `\0`. Is that what you meant by [NULL STRING]?
That expression could be `/([0-9]|\0)/`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this, in java, for the last 4 for a CC number.  The field is optional so it could either be empty, or 4 digits.  My solution is:

```
^\d{4}$|^$
```

The is passing this a null in the typical java fashion results in a null pointer exception:

```
String myString = null;
last4Pattern.matcher(myString).matches(); //Null in this case.
```

However, I feel that it is more of a Java implementation problem.

Comment: ^\d{4}?$ is shorter :)

Answer (score 0):

As it is not easy to match an empty string but it is generally possible to match anything that is not an empty string, consider to turn it around and *not* match the *opposite* (double negative).
In this example, everything that is *not* (`^`) a *non*-digit (`\D`) for zero or one time (`?`):

### `[^\D]?`

<sub>(or for specific ascii: **`[^\x00-\x29\x3a-\xff]?`**, or unicode: **`[^\u0000-\u0029\u003a-\uffff]?`**)</sub>

Matches an "" (*<empty string>*), "**`0`**", "**`1`**" .. "**`9`**", but not a "", (*<space>*), "**`A`**" (non-digit) or "**`123`**" (any longer string).