# A regular expression that match a specified rules

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want a regular expression which accept **3** letters at least and **16** as max and which accept this following : all letters **A** to **Z**  upper case and lower case and the .(dot) and numbers

I am using **JavaScript**

Comment: What are letters, you first say `3-16` letters, and then you define letters otherwise.

Comment: In javascript why the votedown ?

Comment: @Maroxtn I am not the down voter. I think people are too stupid to understand that this question could be helpful for others (even if it seems duplicated or whatever).

Comment: @AvinashRaj Do you really give a damn about what he tried?

Comment: @Barmar What do you want?

Comment: @nbro SO is not about getting other people to write code for you. You're supposed to show some effort, post what you tried, explain what problem you're having, and then we'll help you fix it.

Comment: @CommuSoft All letters upper and lower case and and the number of the letters must not reach more than 16 and numbers and . are allowed

Comment: Your description is not very clear. Can you post examples of strings that should match and strings that shouldn't?

Comment: @Barmar I just think that there's not need to down vote this question, even if it's not the clearest question ever posted.

Comment: @Barmar who told i never tried to make a one and i am not asking from anyone to write code for me i am asking for regex and its allowed and if you want check those question [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063977/regex-empty-string-or-email) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809613/preg-match-empty-string) and those question are not like my case

Comment: If you tried to make it, you should have posted your attempt. Then we could help you understand what you did wrong, and you'll learn. You don't learn from being spoon-fed answers.

Comment: The question says that 3 letters are required. The answer you accepted will allow all numbers and dots, with no letters. Did you mean 3 characters?

Comment: Yes 
      Stackoverflow: accepted    staaaackoverflow : false 
      st4ckoverflow : accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple regex to do this is the following:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9.]{3,16}$
```

The regex works as follows:

- `[A-Za-z0-9.]` accepts any character you have specified;
- `{3,16}` means repeating it `3` to `16` times; and
- `^` and `$` means the start and end fo the string. So that it does not match other parts of the string.

Thus:

```
var str = "Wa89dadb...w";
var res = str.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9.]{3,16}$/g);
```