# Check value with preg_match if have else parsing empty value

Tags: php

I want to check a input value with preg_match. So if user insert anything on input field, preg_match check this value else return error. But if have no input value, sql save only empty field.

When I insert anything on input field, preg_match working well but if input value is empty this preg_match stop insert anything on sql.

here is this:

```
$langu = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['langu']);
$relig = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['relig']);

if(preg_match("/^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/i", $langu) || preg_match("/^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/i", $relig)){
// insert at sql
// If $langu or $relig is empty store empty, but I cannot parsing empty value by preg_match
} else { echo 'error';}
```

Comment: I think you need to add an extra or condition which allows if they were empty also

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preg Match Empty String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809613/preg-match-empty-string)

Comment: Is each value dependent on the other, or can you have `langu` without `relig`? If independent make two conditionals. If dependent then make the `||` into `&&` so both regexs must match.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the string is empty first:

```
if(
   (!empty($langu) && preg_match("/^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/i", $langu)) || 
   (!empty($relig) && preg_match("/^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/i", $relig))
) {
```

(formatted so you can see conditions)

Comment: Thank you sir, but its not work, cannot insert empty value.